Browser requested asset from script tag and adding Accept-Encoding to header
Simplified question:
Is there a way to add an attribute to the  tag in HTML to have the browser request the resource with an 'Accept-Encoding' header?  If not, is there a way to put something else on the HTML page that would force all resources requested to use a specified 'Accept-Encoding' header?  I feel like I am missing something obvious.
Background:
I have an angular 15 application that generates 3 resources and includes them on my page at the bottom at build time.  They look something like this:
<script src="runtime.664207fe9f6f8664.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.62c256ad9ed0a5e3.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.b9faa88b222f8bec.js" type="module"></script>

All of the requests I make using HttpClient can easily be set to do webservice requests with Accepts-Encoding (cannot remember if I set it or it was out of the box).  But the src referenced items do not seem to have any way to request encoding.
After doing some performance tuning, one suggestion is to compress these files and short of forcing the application server to always compress even without the Accept-Encoding header present, I am not sure how to solve this problem.  Thanks in advance.
